# Modify console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to modify `console.log` so that it saves everything that the application outputs to the command line using `console.log`.

I have tried

```
var log = console.log;

console.log = function () {
    // fs.appendFile('log.txt ..
    log.apply(log, arguments);
}
```

But it gives me the error

```
 Illegal invocation
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first arguments to `apply` is what `this` will refer to. To mimic a call to `console.log()`, you have to pass `console`, not the function itself:

```
 var log = console.log;

 log.apply(console, arguments);
 // log.apply(this, arguments); would work as well
```

Comment: Especially since `console.log` has special context rules that require `console` to be its `this` when it runs.

Comment: Why can't I write just `console.log` instead of `log`? Isn't `log` a reference to `console.log` ?

Comment: @afonso-bot: `console.log` would refer to your new method, so you would have a recursive function with no termination condition.

Comment: AMAZING!! 
Works wonderful, I would only include in the answer the first original line which is still necessary for whoever applies this.